# Github private repo with custom ssh key - Repository not found

Tags: git, github, ssh

Using OSX Montery.

I'm trying to access my private repo using a custom ssh key.

I have a custom ssh key "mykey" and "mykey.pub" using

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@gmail.com"`

I have added this key to the ssh agent using

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/mykey`

I have added the key from mykey.pub to my github account with read/write permissions

My ~/.ssh/config looks as follows:

```
Host gmail
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
    User git
    HostName github.com
    UseKeychain yes
```

When I run
`ssh gmail` I get the respone

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

This leads me to believe that my setup is working, using the correct credentials.

However when I try to clone my repository (github.com:Username/myrepo.git) via

`git clone gmail:Username/myrepo.git`

I get

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried multiple variations of this:

```
git clone gmail@github.com:Username/myrepo.git
git clone git@gmail:Username/myrepo.git
git clone git@github.com:Username/myrepo.git --config core.sshCommand="ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey"
```

All to no avail.

`GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone gmail:Username/myrepo.git`
Does nothing for me either, I get the same response every time.

I'm at my wits end, not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Running `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone gmail:Username/myrepo.git` will yield the following result:

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for gmail
debug1: /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/config line 39: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/mykey type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/mykey-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-3d700a2c
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-3d700a2c
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:[key]
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:[key] explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/mykey RSA SHA256:[key] explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: myemail@gmail.com RSA SHA256:[key] agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:[key] explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:[key] explicit agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: ED25519 SHA256:[jkey]
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-ed25519 SHA256:[key]
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.121.4]:22).
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:[key]
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:[key]
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:[key]
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key under different name/addr at /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key under different name/addr at /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key under different name/addr at /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key under different name/addr at /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key under different name/addr at /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key under different name/addr at /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key under different name/addr at /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 2 new, 18446744073709551615 retained, 2 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: host key found matching a different name/address, skipping UserKnownHostsFile update
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 5 IP_TOS 0x20
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug3: Ignored env nvm_current_version
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug1: channel 0: setting env GIT_PROTOCOL = "version=2"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env __CFBundleIdentifier
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env GIT_SSH_COMMAND
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env GIT_EXEC_PATH
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack 'Username/myrepo.git'
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 29
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 6 efd 8 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 8/(29)
ERROR: Repository not found.
debug2: channel 0: written 29 to efd 8
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 7 efd 8 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r43 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/8 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2248, received 2280 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 7842.5, received 7954.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

So for some reason my id_ed25519 will be used. I have it in my config file as my default key:

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Normally I would want to use that key, however it is already associated with another Github account (which is why I want to use a different key in the first place).

Even though my "mykey" key gets recognized first:

```
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/mykey type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/mykey-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
```

Later on the id_ed25519 key is used first:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:[key] explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/mylocalusername/.ssh/mykey RSA SHA256:[key] explicit agent
debug1: Will attempt key: myemail@gmail.com RSA SHA256:[key] agent
```

I'm assuming whats happening is that github recognizes the ed25519 key, but of course that key has no access to that repository and so I'm denied.

I thought this might be because of my known_hosts file, which contained an entry for github.com referring to my id_ed25519 key, but even after deleting it the id_ed25519 key will be used first, only that it asks me to add it to my known hosts:

```
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
```

The only reason I could think of was that my key was RSA, so I regenerated it as ed25519, but I get the same result. Can I somehow force git to use the "mykey" key and not look for others?

Comment: `GIT_TRACE=1 git clone gmail:Username/myrepo.git` ??? `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone gmail:Username/myrepo.git` ???

Comment: `Hi username` - this one is lowercase (`u`sername), the others are uppercase (`U`sername); are you sure you're identifying as the user you intend?

Comment: @phd GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone gmail:Username/myrepo.git was very insightful, please see my edit.

Comment: @torek these are different and should be, the Username is a stand-in for my github account, the lower case username is my local username (I think, honestly I'm unsure where that name comes from), it's just what's in the response from github.

Comment: "*Can I somehow force git to use the gmail key…?*" Either using `~/.ssh/config`. Or you can pass it using the technique you've already learned: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey" git clone gmail:Username/myrepo.git`. The solution with `~/.ssh/config` is preferable as it's more permanent. To debug the situation please tell us if the section `Host gmail` is above or below `Host *` in `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: Aha: you want to add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to your `Host` config here, to tell it "do not use the defaults, only the ones listed in the config". (But this should affect the ssh that Git runs, and the one you run manually, the same way, so it's a mystery if that alone works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pointed me in the right direction.
`IdentitiesOnly yes`
was indeed what I was looking for. After that only the matching rules in the config applied, which still lead to the id_ed25519 being preferenced (regardless of wether it was on the top or the bottom of my config file, not sure why that is, but whatever).

To prevent this from happening I had to exclude it from being applied to the gmail host.

https://superuser.com/questions/859661/how-can-i-force-ssh-to-ignore-the-identityfile-listed-in-host-for-one-specif answered that for me.

So to get it working my ~/.ssh/config had to look like this:

```
Host gmail
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykey
    User git
    HostName github.com
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
Host * !gmail
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

With that the following command (and all subsequent git commands) will work:

```
git clone gmail:Username/myrepo.git
```

Comment: My advice is to change the order: first `Host gmail` then `Host *`. When `ssh` reads its config the first found command wins so config should be written from the most specific to the most generic. `Host gmail` is the most specific and should be the first; `Host *` is the least specific, the most generic and should be the last in the config. Then you don't need `!gmail` in `Host * !gmail`.

Comment: For some reason the id_ed25519 will always be used first, regardless of the order, so without the !gmail it does not work. I have adjusted my answer anyways, as I too think having the generic Host at the end is the better way, even though in this case it does not seem to affect the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If the authentication is valid (`ssh gmail` works), but the repository URL cannot be "read", it can only means:

- the URL is incorrect (case sensitive, or typo)
- the username is not the same as the one authenticated, and is not a collaborator of the target private repository.

Comment: I did get some more insight, apparently my defined keyfile gets ignored in favor of another one (see my edit), so yeah, since the wrong keyfile is used it is not recognized as a collaborator on the account I want to access.

Comment: @DanRockstone Well done and good feedback. Upvoted.